# Esri Terrain-Tools v1.1 Sky Tool Cannot Save File

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hillshade, error-010240, terrain-tools

I am trying to use [Esri Terrain-Tools v1.1](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/06/24/terrain-tools-1-1-released/) with ArcMap 10.5 to create a hillshade from either a 90 m [SRTM DEM](http://www.cgiar-csi.org/data/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v4-1) or 30 m DEM. I have tried saving this to a file geodatabase (FGDB) and .tif. In both cases the error reported is cannot save to "output format" GRID/TIFF

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GIS_local\TOOLS\TerrainTools_v1_1\Scripts\SkyModel.py", line 81, in <module>
    skymodel(*args)
  File "C:\GIS_local\TOOLS\TerrainTools_v1_1\Scripts\SkyModel.py", line 63, in skymodel
    prevRaster.save(outRaster)
RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to C:\GIS_local\hillshade\sky1.tif with output format TIFF.

Failed to execute (SkyModel).
Failed at Mon Feb 26 17:18:37 2018 (Elapsed Time: 3 hours 46 minutes 44 seconds)
```

The output file path is to a local internal drive, scratch filepath is to local default GDB, and there should be more than adequate space to save the file. This seems to have been commonly reported in the past in comments on the [ESRI website](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/06/24/terrain-tools-1-1-released/), but no answer was provided.

Does anyone have thoughts on what may be causing this error?

Comment: Are you *sure* you got enough space to store the entire image? What happens if you try to save to C:\SomeFolder? The path might have some invalid characters. Is the path stated in the error message the *exact* path for the error or has that been sanitized for web viewing? Is the script compiled or can you edit it? If so what's happening around line 63?

Comment: Indeed, the "..." part is where the error is located.

Comment: @Vince, sorry, I should have specified, "..." was just to shorten the file path; I manually edited it here. I can edit it to have a word there as an example.

Comment: @Michael Stimson, unless the output is 900 GB or so there should be enough space. I can try a different file path tomorrow ti see if that is the issue. Thank you for your thoughts on this, I would not think the file path to a local drive would have an issue, but it might.

Comment: The hillshade algorithm is not that involved -- Three hours is far too long to run on a local disk, even if the extent is the continental US. Please edit the question ro provide the dimensions of the input raster. All in all, this seems more a task for Esri Tech Support than GIS SE.